# Event delegate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, delegates

I have a list of divs, that I want to add "onmouseover" events to. I try to iterate over the list of elements, and redefine the "onmouseover" function like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
   elements[i].onmouseover = function() { alert('FOO') }; 
}
```

Unfortunately, after the page finishes loading, it looks like this only gets applied to the very last element. I'm sure this is a real newbie question, but I still haven't figured it out...

Here's a better example exhibiting my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qajPM/

Comment: Your assignment is lacking a } at the end.

Comment: Try using `jquery`, it'll help you a lot.

Comment: Similar code works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqCef/ How is the `elements` array created? Is your code in an onload handler, or at the end of the body _after_ all the divs in question?

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right. I added a better example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qajPM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating all of your div elements like this:

```
parent.innerHTML += "<div> " + i + "</div>"
```

As I'm sure you know that is equivalent to `parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML + ...`, but the `.innerHTML` property returns the html as a string (without any already associated event handlers) so each time you do that it is overwriting the entire innerHTML of the `parent` div with a new string, which means you are effectively adding to the text contents but clobbering the `mouseover` handlers you've already setup.

Try instead something like this:

```
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = i;
parent.appendChild(el);
```

Which appends a new element without affecting the ones already there.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qajPM/1/

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is instead of assigning an event handler to every `div`, you could assign one handler to the parent, then simply fetch which `div` was moused over based on the event target.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('parent').onmouseover = function(e) {
    var target = e.target || e.currentTarget;
    alert('Target ' + target.innerHTML + ' was moused over');
};
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhpLA/

As others have pointed out jQuery also makes this have slightly less code (though if this is all you need it for it would be pointless):

```
$('#parent').on('mouseover', 'div', function(e) {
    alert('Target ' + e.currentTarget.innerHTML + ' was moused over');
});
```

The advantage to the above jQuery code is that it will apply both to current and *future* child `div`s of `#parent`.  If you were to programatically add more the `mouseover` event would continue to work for them as well.

Comment: jquery is great, but I can't justify importing the library just to solve this one problem.

Comment: Of course, which is why the fiddle is in plain 'ol javascript. ;)

Comment: This would work if all divs had the same parent. This isn't the case now, and it's not necessarily a restriction I want to add.